# How to compile to a single release exe from VS2012 without installer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I realise similar questions have previously been asked but nobody really seems to get to the bottom of it.
I am developing in a work environment where policy restrictions prevent users from installing software on their computers. I have created a VB project and am compiling the release to distribute but I just want a clean single .exe file, which I can put in a folder on a network drive and people can access at will.

Whenever I compile, I get the background files externally from the exe (vshost, config, manifest etc.).

My end users are not tech savvy, and are never really sure which file to open. Now, save creating a shortcut and hiding the program files away, is there another way of creating a single, rolled up, all-in-one, exe file for distribution?

Comment: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that an Installer? My end users won't be able to do anything with installers.

Comment: Strange policy that allows users to run any program, but not install any program! At a previous workplace we developed an application that was deployed through clickonce. The domain policy would only allow executables to be run that were signed by a trusted certificate - so we signed the application exe & clickonce manifests as part of the build process. From an end user perspective it was pretty much seamless.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the other files (maybe only the .pdb depending on what kind of application you've made, and what code you use). Just copy the output .exe to the drive and it should be fine, IF it doesn't use any special dlls.

Comment: Just compile for "release" instead of "debug" and you won't even need the pdb. As said in this answer, just copy the `.exe` file only to wherever you want it and it should be stand alone (**if and only if** you didn't use reference to external `dll`s. If you use `dll`s, just place a copy of the `.dll` files alongside your executable in your final folder.)

Comment: @Hoki : Even though I used `Release` for a previous project, I still had to include the .pdb in order for my application to work completely. I used a StackTrace to know on which line an error occured, and that only works with the .pdb.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this code after registerign Form Close Event

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var name in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory))
        {
            if (name.Contains("manifest") || name.Contains(".pdb"))
                System.IO.File.Delete(name);
        }
    }
```

You also need to close Visual Studio Window